# QScrollArea with a QWidget in a QSplitter

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qwt, qscrollarea

I´m making a project for my class, and I need to put a `scrollArea` in a widget (I choosed a splitter) and I want to push a button and create more `scrollArea` inside this widget. This is what I´ve done:

I create the button like this:

```
self.AddCanal = QAction(QIcon(), "Add channel", self, shortcut = "Shift+Ctrl+c", triggered = self.addChannel)
```

And I put it in a `QToolBar()`.

Then, I create the `scrollArea`. I put the scrollArea with the `Qwidget` (in this case I use a `QwtPlot`) in a `QSplitter` (`splitter1`), and then I put a frame and the splitter in another splitter (`splitter2`). And at last, I put `splitter2` and another frame in one last splitter (`splitter3`). You can see it here:

```
self.scrollLayout = QFormLayout()
self.canal = QwtPlot()
self.canal.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)
self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.canal)

self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.canal)

splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter2.addWidget(self.frame)
splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)

splitter3 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
splitter3.addWidget(splitter2)
splitter3.addWidget(self.frame_3)
```

I made it like this, because in one frame I will put a tree widget, and in the bottom frame i will put a `QtextEdit()`.

Well, now I need that the button, when click it, creates another `scrollArea` in the `splitter1`. And I want to create at minimum 5 extra `scrollAreas`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it creating a method like this:

```
def addChannel(self):
    global channelCount
    self.scrollLayout = QFormLayout()

    self.canal = QwtPlot()
    self.canal.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)

    self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.canal)

    if channelCount <= 5:           
        self.splitter1.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        channelCount += 1
        return channelCount
```

using "channelCount" as a global variable starting it in 1, just because i only want 5.

And i add:

```
self.addchannel()
```

at the `QMainWindow` class

Hope it can help somebody.